# BASH Function with Parameter Switches

Tags: bash, function, shell

I want to create a BASH script where I could enter a parameter which would determine what kind of output I will get from vmstat.

My current script looks like this, but it's too rigid:

```
#!/bin/bash

start_perfmon () {
    vmstat -S M -n -w 3 >> $(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M")_Overall.log & vmstat -d -S M -n -w 3 >> HDD_RAW.log
}

start_perfmon
```

It should work like so:

./start_perfmon.sh overall - runs:

```
vmstat -S M -n -w 3 >> $(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M")_Overall.log
```

./start_perfmon.sh disk - runs:

```
vmstat -d -S M -n -w 3 >> HDD_RAW.log
```

./start_perfmon.sh runs the code I have right now:

```
vmstat -S M -n -w 3 >> $(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M")_Overall.log & vmstat -d -S M -n -w 3 >> HDD_RAW.log
```

I have created a mockup script of how I would do it in PowerShell:

(I believe people who could help me, understand the logic, without actually knowing much about PowerShell.)

```
Function Start-Perfmon {
[CmdletBinding()]
Param (
    [Parameter(Position=0)]
    [switch]$Overall,
    [Parameter(Position=1)]
    [switch]$Disk
)

If ((!$Overall) -and (!$Disk)) {
    vmstat -S M -n -w 3 >> $(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M")_Overall.log & vmstat -d -S M -n -w 3 >> HDD_RAW.log
}
Else {
    If ($Overall) {
        vmstat -S M -n -w 3 >> $(date +"%Y%m%d-%H%M")_Overall.log
    }
    If ($Disk) {
        vmstat -d -S M -n -w 3 >> HDD_RAW.log
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm misreading this, but what exactly is the problem here?  At first glance the only thing I would do is change the date portion of your script to `$(Get-Date -UFormat "%Y%m%d-%H%M")

Comment: I'd suggest using `| Out-File` instead of `>>` so you can specify encoding and avoid weird write/read errors in the future.

Comment: Use a `case` statement, with cases for `overall)`, `disk)` and `*)`(default)

Comment: nono.. the PowerShell script is just a sample of how I WOULD do it in PowerShell, but I need it in BASH.. in Linux :)

Comment: That's pretty misleading.  I'd remove your powershell tag.  (also, powershell is supported on linux/mac)

Comment: @Ramil unfortunately stack overflow is here to help you with code issues, not as a free coding service.  Give it a shot and when you are stuck with a specific issue, I'd recommend posting it under the `bash` or `linux` tags

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.owsiak.org/argument-parsing-in-bash/ You can pass arguments to functions the same way you would pass them to application itself.

Comment: PowerShell tag is removed and I did have bash tag. I'm not waiting for people to do the coding for me, I need a direction, which Tom Fenech provided me. I will give it a try.

Comment: Thanks @TomFenech ! I was able to get exactly what I wanted after some testing and searching the internet.